# Have any Rabbis discussed hating Hashem as being part of a deeper level of a relationship with him?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, faith-bitachon-emunah, emes-truth-honesty, avodath-hashem

There's a belief that the people you love the most are the ones who can make you hurt the most. Friends & family have a closeness to us which can hurt us in a deeply personal way. The anger and betrayal you feel from a loved one breaking your trust typically hurts much more deeply than a stranger doing the same.

**The key to that pain is personal bond. The closer someone is to you, the worse that pain and anger is.**

My question is could such a concept relate to a relationship with Hashem?

Hating or having extreme anger towards God is not taken lightly. You shouldn't hate God. That being said, could anger be argued as being a higher level of relationship with Hashem? The idea being it's an honest expression and it's an expression which a person could not feel if they didn't truly believe in Hashem and didn't truly have trust and love for Hashem in the first place. ***(If you didn't have faith and trust in Hashem, the feeling of betrayal wouldn't exist because you didn't believe he'd be there for you anyway.)***

I was curious if this topic was ever touched upon by the Rabbis at any level?

Comment: There's the reverse, at least: that God punishes those he's closest to for what seem to be more minor infractions than he does the rest of us. (Citation needed. Try commentaries to Leviticus 10:3 maybe.)

Comment: @msh210 https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.5a.11

Comment: @msh210 : the rock incident comes as an example to mind. Though some argue that this 'punishment' was in fact a blessing (in disguise)

Comment: @msh210 Maybe you meant [Yevamot 121b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.121b.8?lang=bi&lang2=en): "אמר רבי אבא ... שנאמר 'וסביביו נשערה מאד' מלמד שהקדוש ברוך הוא מדקדק עם סביביו כחוט השערה" (though I remember it from [Mesilat Yesharim ch. 4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mesilat_Yesharim.4.21?lang=bi&lang2=en), who brings it as "מדקדק עם **חסידיו** כחוט השערה").

Comment: Rabbi Manis Friedman says this all the time. People who are angry at Hashem - that's amazing. He is so _real_ to them, it is enviable.